# WooCommerce custom product tabs

Tags: wordpress, tabs, woocommerce

I've created a custom product tabs in the backend and frontend, so other kind of product descriptions can be added and displayed:

```
function custom_product_tab($tabs) {
    $tabs['ctab1'] = array(
        'title'     => __('Custom Tab 1', 'woocommerce'),
        'priority'  => 5,
        'callback'  => 'ctab1_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function ctab1_tab_content() { ?>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>Content....</p>
   <p><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_custom_field', true ); ?></p>
   <?php
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_product_tab');
```

Now in the backend I also created a custom tab to add the description:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', 'woo_add_sana_tabs' );

function woo_add_sana_tabs() { ?>
    <li class="ctab1_tab"><a href="#ctab1_tab"><?php _e('Custom Tab 1', 'woocommerce'); ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
```

Question is how do I add a field input in that specific backend custom tab? I know how to add a custom field in the product general options tab using the woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data hook, but not in this case...

Answer (score -1):

You need to subscribe to woocommerce_product_write_panels hook to write the panel for your custom tab

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_write_panels', 'woo_add_sana_panel');

function woo_add_sana_panel()
{
    ?>
        <div id="ctab1_tab" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">
            <h1>Sana Heading</h1>
            <!-- Add whatever you want -->
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will add fields to all existing tabs.

Comment: As I have seen it in the codes, woocommerce_product_write_panels action hook is called only after rendering all other tabs so, I doubt it. Have tried it yourself?

Comment: Of course. And the custom field was added to all tabs.

Comment: Please try using woocommerce_product_data_panels action hook instead of woocommerce_product_write_panels, although woocommerce_product_write_panels worked in the version I used, it seem to be deprecated. Please keep me posted, thanks